# create a counter that updates every second

Tags: javascript

I want to create a counter for my site, this is my cod,right now evry 1000 millisecond it increment 1 unit but i want that evry 1000 millisecond it increment todaycostsec ???

```
<html>
<script language="javascript">

sumcost=4000;
todaycost=500;
todaycostsec=(500)/86400;
var sum;
var Min;
Min=(sumcost-todaycost);

function incrementer() {
    sum=(Min+todaycostsec);
    document.time.heure.value=sum;
    //document.time.result.value=sum;
}

function incrementer1() {
    sum++;
    //sum= Math.ceil(Min + ( todaycost* todaycostsec));
    document.time.heure1.value=sum;
}

interv = setInterval("incrementer1()",1000);

</script>

<form name="time">
    <input type="text" value="" name="heure" onclick="incrementer();"/>  
    <input type="text" value="" name="heure1" onclick="incrementer1();"/>
    <div align="center">
        <script language="JavaScript">
        //document.write('<input style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold; bo ?rder: none; color:#CC0000 ; FONT-SIZE: 14pt; TEXT-ALIGN: center;" name=result size=30 value="incrementer()">');
        </script>
    </div>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Please stop passing the function as a string in `setInterval`! Pass it as a reference : `setInterval(incrementer1, 1000);`

Comment: @Arun P Johny it doesn't work, it increment in to the wrong way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
function incrementer1() {
    sum += todaycostsec;
    document.time.heure1.value=sum;
}
```

Comment: i used this and it work ..                                                          function incrementer1() {
sum +=(todaycostsec);
document.time.heure1.value=sum;
}

Comment: @user2515311 that was what I meant, the syntax `sum += x`

Comment: @user2515311 I'a doubt about what was the actual value you want to increment by